# Creating DC Linechart (or Serieschart) based on Fake 'Prediction' Group

Tags: d3.js, fft, prediction, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to transpose to a dc linechart or serieschart the predict function using the library fft.js described in that page : [prediction Fourier](https://antoinevastel.com/algorithme/s%C3%A9ries%20temporelles/2016/06/05/prediction-fourier.html) (in french) and rendered in highchart for example.

[image: The render result in highchart]

My first step to pass the dimension group into the function is to convert only the values to an array (maybe it exist a better way).

Dimension group look like this before :

```
(12) […]
​
0: Object { key: 1, value: 703 }
​
1: Object { key: 40, value: 203 }
​
2: Object { key: 41, value: 309 }
​
3: Object { key: 42, value: 166 }
​
4: Object { key: 43, value: 193 }
​
5: Object { key: 44, value: 166 }
​
6: Object { key: 45, value: 218 }
​
7: Object { key: 46, value: 159 }
​
8: Object { key: 47, value: 200 }
​
9: Object { key: 48, value: 203 }
​
10: Object { key: 49, value: 239 }
​
11: Object { key: 50, value: 161 }
​
length: 12
```

```
 var donnee = DataDim.group();
                var a = donnee.all();
                datap = new Array();
                for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) { // i = 1 because i need to remove the first key/value pair
                    x = a[i].value
                    if (x > 0) {
                        datap.push(x)
                    }
                };

            var donnees = datap; // array to pass into predict function
```

console.log(donnees);

```
(11) […]
​
0: 203
​
1: 309
​
2: 166
​
3: 193
​
4: 166
​
5: 218
​
6: 159
​
7: 200
​
8: 203
​
9: 239
​
10: 161
​
length: 11
```

And after passing into the prediction function :

```
const result = prediction.map(function (x) {
                    return parseInt(x, 10);
                });
                console.log(result)
(15) […]
​
0: 202
​
1: 308
​
2: 166
​
3: 193
​
4: 165
​
5: 218
​
6: 159
​
7: 200
​
8: 203
​
9: 239
​
10: 161
​
11: 165
​
12: 271
​
13: 128
​
14: 155
​
length: 15
```

For now, because i'm beginner in javascript, i don't know how to return the array into a fakegroup looking like the original group with added data.

​This is the array i need for my .all fakegroup :

```
0: Object { key: 40, value: 202 } // New predicted value
​
1: Object { key: 41, value: 308 }
​
2: Object { key: 42, value: 166 }
​
3: Object { key: 43, value: 193 }
​
4: Object { key: 44, value: 165 }
​
5: Object { key: 45, value: 218 }
​
6: Object { key: 46, value: 159 }
​
7: Object { key: 47, value: 200 }
​
8: Object { key: 48, value: 203 }
​
9: Object { key: 49, value: 239 }
​
10: Object { key: 50, value: 161 }

11: Object { key: 51, value: 165 }

12: Object { key: 52, value: 271 }

13: Object { key: 1, value: 128} // Need restart at 1 because it's the WeekOfYear

14: Object { key: 2, value: 155}
​
length: 15
```

Trying to understand method described in these answers but i think it is not adapted for my problem :

[dc.js Using two reducers without a simple dimension and second grouping stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677899/dc-js-using-two-reducers-without-a-simple-dimension-and-second-grouping-stage)
[dc.js Incorporate regression chart into existing scatterplot with crossfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892232/dc-js-incorporate-regression-chart-into-existing-scatterplot-with-crossfilter)

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT 1 :**

Here is the solution I have found for the moment, but I think it is not at all optimized, but it works in part for the desired result.

```
function fakepredict(donnee, horizon, nb_harmonique){

    return {
            all: function () {
                var a = donnee.all();
                datav = new Array();
                datax = new Array();

                for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
                    x = a[i].value
                    datav.push(x)
                };

                var datav = predict(datav, horizon, nb_harmonique);
                var first = a[1].key;
                var ln = datav.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
                    k = i + first;
                // if (k > 52){k = (i + horizon) - (ln + 1)};
                    var kv = { key: k, value: datav[i] };
                    datax.push(kv);
                };


               console.log(datax);

                return datax;

                        }
                   };
              }
```

[image: Desired result]

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n49pv50c/)

Comment: I got deep into answering this and then figured out I couldn't explain your original group - why does it start with key 1, then skip to 40, run to 50 and stop? Even if it's out of order, I find that hard to understand - are weeks 51 and 52 missing? It takes more learning, but it's generally better to use a date scale when dealing with dates - each key would be a full date with year, and then you could print just the week number if that's what you want, but you wouldn't have to worry about wrapping or overlap.

Comment: Creating a fake group is easy, and mapping your array values back to group values isn't all that hard, but I'm concerned that the original data might be out of order, in which case the result wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Hello Gordon, yes, the data represents dates converted to weeks. Each item corresponds to a unique 'ticket' with an opening date and a closing date. For this I import two csv files, the first including tickets with opening dates and having been closed for the last 10 weeks. The second includes open tickets without closing date so (I need them for the display of another graph). The size of the group I want to predict is all tickets closed, only when that crossfilter does not find a closing date, it puts them in the first key (0: Object { key: 1, value: 703 }).

Comment: I think I should therefore filter it upstream by a fake group but I don't have the solution yet, empty bin didn't work on.

Comment: I advanced on the programming of my fake 'prediction' group, I update the question by an edit

Comment: Cool, looks like you figured it out. Congrats! If you have further questions, don’t hesitate to ask. P.S. crossfilter uses the key functions you provide to generate the group, so you could put the unclosed tickets in whatever bin you like.

Comment: BTW, in the future, it's better form to add an answer to your question when you figure it out yourself. Not a big deal, but it makes it more helpful to people who stumble on your question in the future.