# Scatter Plot with linear regression and confidence interval

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Hey i am confused about scatter plot working with regression line and confidence interval and is my box plot is right. I need help regrading this issues. The box plot i draw and the box plot which is displaying i think it is different.
The following are the files regarding to box plot.

[image: My Box Plot]

[image: Data Set]

[image: Required BXP]

the both built on same data set but dc box plot showing outlier on 35 but in required bxp the max whisker is on 35. is it possible that one of them is incorrect. Moreover, is it possible to display tooltip like this.

The second thing is to draw a scatter plot with this data set having dimension of Avg Piper OPG Count like in below pic.

[image]

is it possible to make dimension and group like this to draw Scatter plot or is there any workaround.

Should i have 2 data set or is it possible with this data set which i used for Box Plot. More i want to draw a regression line and confidence interval which i think can be done with line chart like in this link.

https://observablehq.com/@toja/linear-regression-with-confidence-bands
https://github.com/ptsurko/d3-linregr-sample

is it possible to do these things with dc.js by some way. or should i use regression.js to get values for regression.

I am new to these things and i am learning through dc helping community, thanks to you people. Can anyone help me with such scenario. I am pretty much confuse. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, but [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot#Elements_of_a_box_plot) the whiskers can represent various different measures, such as min/max, 1 standard deviation, or different percentiles. Take a look at the IQR (interquartile range) code in [box-plot.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/charts/box-plot.js) for undocumented ways to customize this.

Comment: Here's [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892232/dc-js-incorporate-regression-chart-into-existing-scatterplot-with-crossfilter) on adding a linear regression line to a scatter plot. I may have a complete example somewhere.

Comment: Can you tell me is it possible with this data set to make dimension and measures for these graphs one include sum and scatter plot dimension is avg and measure is also avg. Can i make dimension on avg or should i have to solve it with fake group.

Comment: What about tooltip can we use tooltip like this doing any workaround

Comment: This kind of general discussion would work better [on the users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group). Yes, you can do averages using crossfilter group reductions - the [annotated source for the stocks example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) shows one way.

Comment: And yes of course you can do tooltips on any chart, it’s only tricky when you have a brush because the brush will intercept the mouse. I’m not clear how that relates to this question.

Comment: I created a minimal [linear regression example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/regression.html) for dc.js.

Comment: I worked on regression line with confidence interval. But i was stuck with d3.area() as i wasn't know how the area draw in svg. so i move my this chart to d3. But i would like to open a discussion with my code. so maybe you could suggest a better complete example of this scenario. 
Should i open this discussion in dc user group or should i post my code and related working on stackoverflow.

Comment: If there is a specific question, then SO is better; if it's a broad discussion then the user group is better. Maybe ask a question with a picture of the effect you want? Since I think there may be different ways of visualizing confidence intervals. It would be nice to expand that example.